# Playing music in the background and switching views

Tags: ios, swift

So I've been trying to add BGM to my app, it works but whenever I switch to another view and then switch back, it would layer the BGM again.
I've tried googling, and I see other people with the same problem,
the only point I'm stuck here is that I'm not coding it with Objective-C, I'm coding with Swift, and besides a whole lot of Taylor Swift, I can't find solutions D:

The following are the codes that I use to write the BGM.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var ButtonSound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("tamborine", ofType: "wav")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

   /* var Bgm = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Waiting-in-the-Woods", ofType: "mp3")!), error: nil) */

    func playBgMusic(){
        let musicPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Waiting-in-the-Woods", ofType: "mp3")
        let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: musicPath!)
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        //-1為循環播放
        audioPlayer.volume = 1
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.play()


    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: ButtonSound, error: nil)

               //Bgm.play()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        playBgMusic()
        if !audioPlayer.playing {
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewWillAppear, you call playBgMusic() which in turn calls audioPlayer.play()

So the fact that the tracks are starting over makes sense because that's what you asked it to do. I think the logic you need is something along the lines of the following.

```
if !audioPlayer.playing {
  playBgMusic()
}
```

or if you like guard statements

```
guard player.playing else {
  playBgMusic()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found out that my other button sounds audioPlayer were named the same as my bgm, problem solved after giving them new names.
I have another question, I want to create a new view for the setting page, to switch off the bgm and other sounds, but I then realize I can't call other functions and properties for the setting page from the original page that has the coding for the sounds, is there anyway possible that I can call them on a new view? Or would I have to put the switches on the same view as the sounds? Thanks a bunch. :D

Comment: Or should I post another question individually? :O

Comment: You can post a notification and listen for it on the controller that owns the player. Assuming that controller isn't deallocated at least.

Comment: I'm not sure how should I post a notification( ´・｀;) This is what I've tried so far.

Comment: oh I can't post the coding ( ´・｀;) I think I might just post another question, thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a new AVAudioPlayer() every time your view loads, making a new track overlaying the previous one(s).

Simply make your audio player class a singleton. This will also allow you to control the music from any scene/screen in your app at any time.

Whenever your home screen loads, check to see if music is already playing, if not, call playBgMusic(), otherwise do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You are constructing a new `AVAudioPlayer` and assign it to `audioPlayer` each time your view loads(ie. when `override func viewDidLoad()` executed by iOS ). So when you load the view again, it is created from scratch and the older one probably still keeps working.